# No member named 'begin' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, xcode, namespaces, std

I successfully compiled on Windows a code that should be crossplatform. Now when compiling it in Xcode with Mac OS X, I get:

```
std::valarray<float> v(32);
...
std::sort(begin(v), end(v));            # Use of undeclared identifier 'begin'
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));  # No member named 'begin' in namespace 'std'
std::sort(std::valarray::begin(v), std::valarray::end(v));  # Idem, error as well
```

Why does the error `No member named 'begin' in namespace 'std'` happen?

Comment: Non-member `begin` is a C++11 feature, try enabling it in XCode.

Comment: @Basj: just saw that while testing :) I confirm that adding -std=c++11 to the command line it compiles fine. I'm glad I haven't answered without testing :)

Comment: when will std=c++11 will become default? come on it's 2016 and there's a lot of questions only solved by adding that switch!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I assume it is some old XCode verson?  I mean, it wouldn't be user-friendly to not include C++11, and this is on a mac, axiomatically it is user-friendly.  heh.

Comment: Just for anyone else looking up, here's one more possibility with maps. If your map is a data member and you're trying to access it inside a non-static class method that is qualified as `const`, then accessing mymap[x] will result in compile time error, because, mymap[x] will create an entry for x if it's already not there, so it's modifying the data member in a function that's marked as `const`, so violation. Use mymap.at(x), if you know that x is already present in mymap, using map.find(x)

Answer (score 6):

`std::begin` was introduced with C++11.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7791906/771073) for how to enable C++11 in XCode 4.2 (the precise name of the dialect has probably changed by now).

Alternatively, if you can't move to C++11, switch to `std::vector` and use `v.begin()`.

Comment: Thanks. About your alternate solution, I get `v.begin()` : `No member named 'begin' in 'std::valarray<float>'`

Comment: @Basj: Yeah.  Sorry about that - I saw your comment above and updated my alternative.

Comment: Even if the OP has C++11 `valarray` does not have a begin and end member function.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes - which is why I suggested switching to vector and using v.begin if he can't get `begin(v)` to work.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  Following on from your comment on a deleted post:  <valarray> is defined to provide an overload of `std::begin` for `valarray`s.

Comment: @MartinBonner Good call.  Missed it was added

Comment: @NathanOliver: Turning on C++11 *is* all you have to do to get the code to work.

Comment: *Somewhere* there should be a "C++ Language Dialect" option - you need to change that (and probably "C++ Standard Library" too).

Comment: @MartinBonner In fact, I cannot use C++11 because it requires OS 10.7 SDK. And for legacy support (my software needs it), I have to use Base SDK = OS X 10.5.  When I enable C++ Language Dialect and C++ Standard Library as you explained, I get `clang error invalid deployment target for stdlib libc++ (requires OS 10.7 or later)`

Comment: Ah.  In that case, either switch to vector + v.begin(), or use &v[0], (&v[0])+v.size().  I'm not sure valarray is guaranteed to be contiguous, but in practise it will be..

Comment: @MartinBonner [It seems to be contiguous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11143184/1422096). What is the difference between your `&v[0]` and @Yakk's `T* begin( std::valarray<T>& v ) { return addressof(v[0]); }` ? In which case the latter is better?

Comment: The difference is that Yakk has taken the trouble to factor out the "get the start of the container" into a separate function.

Comment: @MartinBonner In practice, are there equivalent? I admit I don't understand what does `T* addressof(T& arg) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(
           &const_cast<char&>(
              reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>(arg)));
  }` do. Too much cast for me!

Comment: The problem with &v[0] is that it may not work if the type has an operator&() defined.  addressof is guaranteed to work, and all the casts are to keep the compiler quiet.

Answer (score 2):

You could be compiling in C++03 mode.  Work out how to get your IDE to compile in C++11 mode.  [XCode 4.2 turn on C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7791906/1774667) may help.

`std::sort(std::valarray::begin(v), std::valarray::end(v));` -- I don't think the standard demands this ever work.  I guess if `valarray` implemented `begin` and `end` as statics or Koenig friend operators or somesuch.

`std::valarray` doesn't come with member begin/end.  The only way in C++03 to iterate over it was to use `[]` or with pointers.

[`valarray` is guaranteed to be contiguous.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11143184/1774667).  So you can write

```
namespace notstd {
  // addressof taken from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof
  template<class T>
  T* addressof(T& arg) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(
           &const_cast<char&>(
              reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>(arg)));
  }

  template<class T>
  T* begin( std::valarray<T>& v ) { return addressof(v[0]); }
  template<class T>
  T* end( std::valarray<T>& v ) { return begin(v)+v.size(); }
  template<class T>
  T const* begin( std::valarray<T> const& v ) { return addressof(v[0]); }
  template<class T>
  T const* end( std::valarray<T> const& v ) { return begin(v)+v.size(); }
}
```

and use `notstd::begin` on your `valarray`.

Comment: `begin` and `end` are guaranteed to be in: <array>, <deque>, <forward_list>, <list>, <map>, <regex>, <set>, <string>, <unordered_map>, <unordered_set>, and <vector>.; as well

Comment: @NathanOliver:  ... and <valarray> which is the one of interest here!

Comment: @MartinBonner That because `valarray` does not have a `begin` or `end` member function.  It would be silly to include it as you cannot use it.  By the looks of it any standard header that has begin/end has begin/end included which is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk. In which case this code (with adressof...) is better than replacing begin by `&v[0]` ?

Comment: The real win is in the definition of `end` (in practise `addressof` is hardly ever needed - it's more important for authors of library code that has to work with arbitrary types).

Comment: @basj Martin has it.