# std::begin for valarray on XCode 4 + 10.5 SDK

Tags: c++, std, valarray

I have to build a soft with XCode 4 + Base SDK 10.5 for legacy support.

It seems that I cannot [turn on C++11 as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7791906/1422096) (i.e. by setting "C++ Language Dialect" to "C++11" and "C++ Standard Library" to "libc++"), because when I do it, I get

> clang error invalid deployment target for stdlib libc++ (requires OS 10.7 or later)

Then, as I can't load C++11 (thus, the answers of [my previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874998/no-member-named-begin-in-namespace-std) cannot be used), how should I modify:

```
std::valarray<float> v(32);
std::sort(begin(v), end(v));            # Use of undeclared identifier 'begin'
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));  # No member named 'begin' in namespace 'std'
```

to make it work ?

Comment: "Buy a new computer." -- Apple

Comment: @RyanBemrose I have one, but I need to compile with legacy support ;)

Comment: `v.begin()` and `v.end()` as described by an answer on your previous question

Comment: @Asu This doesn't seem to work for `valarray` : `v.begin() : No member named 'begin' in 'std::valarray<float>'`

Comment: Ah yes, has a non-member `begin` (as of C++11), but not a member one. Makes sense. XD This class is incredibly broken, almost no one uses that for a reason.

Comment: Seems correct. Honestly, I've never heard of valarray before this question. I wonder why C++11 introduced non-members `begin` and `end` without their member counterparts...

Comment: @TreeWithEyes Yes, I also heard about this :). Would you have a solution, without having to move from valarray to vector?

Comment: I fail to see why [this answer you already have](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39875156/4342498) does not work for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver True. At the time of writing this question, I tried, it worked, but wasn't sure if it was the most natural way of doing it. Now, it works and I understand it better, so you're right : this gives the answer. I'll close this one myself.